# How can someone fail casting from a spell scroll

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

In the DMG just before all the magic items there is a variant rule titled “Scroll Mishaps”

> A creature who tries and fails to cast a spell from a *spell scroll* must make a DC 10 Intelligence saving throw. If the saving throw fails, roll on the Scroll Mishap table.

I ask, how does one fail to cast the spell in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If the spell is normally a higher level than you can normally cast

The description of the [*spell scroll*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) magic item on page 200 of the DMG says:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll
> and cast its spell without providing any material components.
> Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

However, if the spell is on your class spell list, but a higher level than you can normally cast, it may fail:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your
> spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully.
> The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a failed check, the spell
> disappears from the scroll with no other effect.

### A *counterspell* may also cause the spell to fail

The description of the 3rd-level spell [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) reads:

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of casting a spell.
> If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd level or lower, its spell
> fails and has no effect.

In an [unofficial tweet from December 2016](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/786982774926249984), rules designer Jeremy Crawford stated:

> When successful, counterspell foils a spell that is cast. The casting
> isn't undone. The spell fails and is wasted.

This means that the Scroll Mishap variant rule will trigger if a *spell scroll* is counterspelled.

Comment: A Q&A semi-related to the second part of your answer: [If a spell cast from a Spell Scroll is Counterspelled, is the scroll consumed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86366/33569)